# Help with my villager breeder

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've created a villager breeder this morning using [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLf0v24pA1w) in minecraft 1.16 java edition.

Everything seems to work correctly (the beds assignments are right, the farmer throws his excess to the others villagers).

But my villagers don't breed. I see heart particles at least 1 time a day but they always end up with storm particles. (when I say always I mean about 10 times in a row)

I don't know if I'm just not lucky or if there is an issue with my villagers. (and I accidentally hit my villagers so I don't know if this could influence their breeding rate but if it does feel free to tell me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stormy particles mean some preconditions are missing, and in particular, most probably, the precondition is lack of free beds, unassigned to any villager (free for the baby to take, except the baby falling down loses the "connection" freeing it for another.)

What you should do is, during the day (when the villagers stand in their cell) break all the beds, and replace them - first making sure no-one can pathfind to them (break any scaffolding / temporary access that let you access this location, and after replacing the beds break the access to them from the "outside" before restoring your safe path out.

Comment: yes this was causing the issue but i think 1.16 changed the villager's pathfinding because  you cannot trick them into thinking an innacessible bed is valid for a baby anymore. (i've tested 5 farm designs in 1.16 and all of them have the save issue.

Comment: @rémicouturier: wait, did you mean "inaccessible bed is *in*valid for a baby anymore"? In many normal breeders like ImpulseSV's (the one you linked) the bed is normally accessible (not even merely pathfindable) to the child - briefly (then the child falls down and the bed is no longer pathfindable). But in general, it seems 'disembarking' code (exitting boats, minecarts, and for that matter, beds) changed in 1.16 so it might be the case.